# Jenkins marks good build as failure because of test failed

Tags: jenkins, build, notifications

Jenkins marks good build as failure because of some unit test failed. If I run the build without unit test, I would get Build Success status. How can I configure Jenkins to do something like this:

1. Build success + Unit Tests fail --> Send out email notification with custom content like Build success  + How many Unit Test Fail.
2. Build success + Unit Tests success --> Send out email notification saying both Build and Unit Tests success
3. Build fail --> Don't run Unit Tests --> Send out email notification on Build fail.

With my Email-ex setup now, I keep getting Build fail (good build) notification if the any unit test fail. I think Jenkins marks good build as failure because of test failed.

Comment: The answer depends on how you are calling your tests. Also depends on your OS (shell behaves a little different than batch in this regard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Maven to manage your project and its dependencies. If yes, you can provide the parameter **-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true** under Maven Project Configuration -> MAVEN_OPTS

Hope this will help you to achieve the functionality that the build will be success even if unit test cases are failing.

Comment: Thanks @dasrohith. Using Maven parameter works for me.

Comment: @KiemNguyen Good to hear that, it worked for you, even-though its late ;)